# Cannot Emit Property of Undefined

Tags: node.js, nestjs

The scenario is after every 3 to 5 API requests I always get this 503 error which crashes the site.

I've checked the logs and found this error.
[image]

Has anyone experienced this before? Our DevOps guy told me he's using AWS EC2. We've migrated from Digital Ocean.

It works fine on our Staging site. Which is a different server.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Comment: @Tyler2P It's inside the node_module though.

Comment: @rainalasa Not necessarily true. You may have `@Output() something: EventEmitter;` without initializing new EventEmitter.

Comment: @GytisTG I see, It was working fine in Digital Ocean though. I just wonder why it fails in AWS.

Comment: @rainalasa In the stack trace it looks like its executing `classToPlain` to convert one of your objects. Please share the class definition for the object that is being converted so that we have more context on what is happening here. It looks like you're just getting a timeout error on some kind of async call

Comment: @rainalasa Sorry, missed your comment. Ok, if it works on one but fails on other, then it's possible to be from node_modules... But in that case I have no idea why it fails.